# How to post multipart form data that includes unknown number of images with Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am creating an application for Android and I have just started using Retrofit 2. I have to upload id, name, code and photos to server but I don't know how to do that with retrofit 2. As you will see from class below I do not know how many photos I will need to upload...

I have this class:

```
class Asset {
    private int mId;
    private int mName;
    private int mCode;
    private ArrayList<String> mPhotos;

    // ... constructor
    // ... getters and setters
}
```

I and this is repository:

```
class AssetsRepository {
    // ... private fields
    // ... constructor

    public void store(Asset asset, final AssetUploadCompletedCallback callback) {
        // What should be the arguments?
        this.mNPApiService.storeAsset(asset.getCode() /*, ...*/)
               .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                       callback.onAssetUploadCompletedCallback();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                       //error handling
                   }
               });
    }

}
```

And NPApiservice interface:

```
interface NPApiService {
    // ... other methods

    @Multipart
    @Post("/assets/{code}")
    Call<String> storeAsset(@Path("code") String code /*, what should go here?*/)
}
```

I also need to have progress bar with percentage so how can I attach listener that will tell me total upload percentage of request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you to upload multiple images with multi-part:

`@Multipart
 @POST(TMB_API_DIR + "/uploadFile")
 Call<DataResponse> uploadImageFiles(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] partMap, @Query("access_token") String accessToken);`

Here we have used Array for Part of MultipartBody with another parameter like access token.

Comment: I have created similar method in my `NPApiService` interface and in repository implemented creation of `MultipartBody.Part[]` array, however i still don't know how can I track upload progress in percentages. I have found this example: https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/34/Retrofit-File-Update-Progress but I have many files and also other parameters like `name`, `id` and `code` inside body of request, and I need total upload percentage of request. Do I subclass RequestBody and MultipartBody.Part, calculate total lenght of my request's body myself, and attach listener as proposed in the example?

Comment: yes - you can go ahead if you can calculate the total length of request body including all images. I have done the same, but without progress according to my requirements.

Comment: I did exactly that, I have extended `RequestBody` class and made my buffer size 4096 bytes long (code is very similar to that link I have posted in previous comment) and I hope buffer size is ok. And everything works!

Comment: Great. Happy codimg

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it. This uploads the whole folder, you may change accordingly to handle your files. You need to use Multipart Format.

Here is a code sample:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("sync/contact/image")
    Call<Response> ImageUpload(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

    @Multipart
    @POST("sync/image")
    Call<ResponseBody> MultiImageUpload(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> mapFileAndName);


 public static HashMap<String, RequestBody> GetAllImage(Context context) {
        File files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/.ELMEX");
        File[] filesArray = files.listFiles();
        List<File> listOfNames = Arrays.asList(filesArray);
        HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>(listOfNames.size());
        RequestBody file = null;

        for (int i = 0, size = listOfNames.size(); i < size; i++) {
            file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), listOfNames.get(i));
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + listOfNames.get(i).getName() + ".jpg", file);
            file = null;
        }

        return  map;
    }


 HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = UtilImage.GetAllImage(context);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = Retro.getRetroWS().MultiImageUpload(map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
            }
        });
```